# What is the necessity of sys.exit(app.exec_()) in PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, exit

I have this code, that works just fine:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def main_window():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()

    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    widget.setWindowTitle("Center!")
    widget.setGeometry(200, 100, screen.width() - 400, screen.height() - 200)

    label = QtGui.QLabel(widget)
    label.setText("Center!")
    label.move(widget.frameGeometry().width() / 2, widget.frameGeometry().height() / 2)

    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_window()
```

Now in the line where I say `sys.exit(app.exec_())`, I can also say `app.exec_()` and both works the same.

So what's the difference and why is it necessary to write `sys.exit()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It just makes you immediately close the program after the Qt Event loop is over, which is in most cases when you close the GUI

Comment: QApplication::exec: Must be called from the main thread

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `exec()` call starts the event-loop and will block until the application quits. If an [exit code has been set](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit), `exec()` will return it after the event-loop terminates. It is good practice to pass on this exit code to `sys.exit()` - but it is not strictly necessary. Without the explicit call to `sys.exit()`, the script will automatically exit with a code of `0` after the last line of code has been executed. A non-zero exit code is usually used to inform the calling process that an error occurred.